# How to set JS Object Parameter whilst returning the JS Object

Tags: clojurescript

I want to create an JavaScript Image object and set the `src` property. I tried:

```
(set! (.-src (js/Image. 80 80)) "foo.png")
```

But the return value of this will be `"foo.png"`.

**How do I set the `src` property and return the `#<[object HTMLImageElement]>`?**

*Ultimately I want to create a sequence of images with the sources "1.png", "2.png"... so was hoping the following would work:*

```
(map (fn [x] (aset (js/Image. 80 80) "src" (str x ".png"))) (range 0 11))
```

Comment: Be advised, though, that `map` is lazy, so you might not get what you expect. You may want to go with `doseq`, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(let [the-image (js/Image. 80 80)]
   (set! (.-src the-image) "foo.png")
   the-image ;;=> the full image is here with the src = foo.png
)
```